# What's the term for a placeholder word with many meanings that can only be determined by context?

Tags: word-request

These are placeholder words like "yeet" and "jawn", which have no meaning in themselves, but can take nearly any meaning depending on their context.

What is the term for these sorts of words?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placeholder_name), they're simply called "placeholder names":

> Placeholder names are words that can refer to objects or people whose names do not exist, are temporarily forgotten, irrelevant, or unknown in the context in which they are being discussed.